# Custom Fonts Defined With @font-face Only Working In Edge

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, fonts

I was trying to add a custom font to my Neocities site, so I used the following css code in my style.css file:

```
body{
font-family: statusplz;
font-size: 10px;
}
p {
}
html {  
background-color: #000100;
color: #999999;
font-size: 14px;
}
h1 {
color: #990033;
font-size: 28px;
}
hr {
color: #660033;
border-color: #660033;    
background-color: #660033;
}

h2 {
}

@font-face {
font-family: 'statusplz';
src: url('https://vaguesoft.neocities.org/statusplz.ttf') format("truetype");
}
```

The custom font does not display in any browser other than Edge. I've used other sites with custom fonts on Firefox, and Chrome. I viewed the css files for those sites using the firefox dev tools, and they also used ttf files and @font-face, but actually worked. I don't know why the font isn't showing up in other browsers. I don't know if the problem is in the css file, the font file, or the html of the site. It was working at some point. It works on one of my computers, but that machine already has the font installed. Maybe I'm not handling frames properly (I do have a sidebar)? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here's a link to the site: https://vaguesoft.neocities.org/

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow!!!
You have to use eot,woff,woff2,svg type of font source to work on modern browsers like chrome firefox.

Comment: Use this url https://onlinefontconverter.com to convert your ttf font to other formats

Comment: @Sharvan Thank you. I had tried adding other font files before, but It seems that when I did, I forgot an apostrophe. I'm still confused as to why some sites only seem to need ttf files, and mine needs more. My problem is now solved, though. Again, thank you very much.